# Internal drive turns read only

Tags: permissions, mount, sudo, fstab, disk

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have an internal 8tb harddrive which I want it to be mounted to all users on my machine both admins and not.

I've created a folder called 8tb in `/media/8tb`

Then I added the below to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 1
```

The harddrive keeps switching to readonly after using it for some time then when I unmount it and remount it it shows the below message asking for an admin account to mount it, not sure what the problem is?

[image]

Here is how it looks in the disks:

[image]

If I mount it with an admin account I get this error message:

[image]

Although in the sudoers file I have this added allowing the non-admin account I have to mount without sudo

```
my_non_admin_user    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/mount.cifs, /bin/mount, /bin/umount
```

I tried changing the fstab file to be like this:

```
/dev/sda /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 2
```

or

```
UUID=629f755c-a29e-43bd-ad02-8deec4abdddb /media/8tb ext4 user,defaults 0 2
```

But still the same thing happens and it turns read only and

and this is the result of `ll /dev/sda`:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 jun 10 22:24 /dev/sda
```

I've run `dmesg` `journalctl` and S.M.A.R.T and placed the results in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bgw1rkbhj1vqrn0/AABGVaqh-LMoc8oAyVwqLwyIa)

I wonder what might be the reason the drive suddenly turns read only? And how to avoid this?

Comment: May be you can try  killall nautilus.

Comment: @AmmarSabirCheema I want to know what may caused the drive to suddenly turn read only.

Answer (score 0):

I really hate to break this to you, but it looks like something is dying in the hardware.

## *Please* back up the files now, because disk failure could happen at any time.

The `Input/output error` you keep seeing indicates something happening outside userland, and I am pretty confident in Linux's SATA drivers. I have seen similar messages to this (and corresponding similar behaviour) before complete disk failure.

The fact that `smartctl` is erroring in this way rules out filesystem corruption as a root cause; it is probably going to be a symptom, however.

There are many better resources online for how to handle this, but I'll try to outline some here. Be aware that *none* of these are as good as a data recovery *specialist*, and **may make the situation worse**. If you care enough about the data that you don't trust some random on SE, you should unplug the thing, pay an expert, and stop reading.

Still here? Here's some steps that could help:

- `rsync -ar /media/8tb $BAK_DIR` where `$BAK_DIR` is a directory capable of holding all the files (and not on the disk)
- `umount /dev/sda; ddrescue /dev/sda $BAK_FILE` where `$BAK_FILE` is a file in a directory capable of holding all the files (and not on the disk)

Now, going into troubleshooting to see if we can fix it: hopefully it is just a dodgy connection:

- Try resetting your BIOS to see if some weirdness is going on there.
- Try using a different cable and a different port on your computer.
- Try plugging it into a different computer, with a different cable.

If none of these work, then your disk is the thing that is broken. If this is the case, then you cannot properly trust the disk again, even if you get it repaired.

Sorry.